# How to Upload both file and data using ajax , jquery and spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I want to upload the data along with the file using ajax , query and Spring MVC  Below is the my modal pop up . please can anyone help me with this out.

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="fileUpload" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="changeTitle">
          <spring:message code="ulearn.summary.mastercourse.addreference" />
        </h4>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="masterCourseItemForm" onsubmit="return false;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name"><spring:message code="ulearn.summary.name.label"/></label>
            
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="" value="" autofocus="true">
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd"><spring:message code="ulearn.summary.description.label"/></label>
            
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="" value=""></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">File Type</label>
            
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="Select" class="selectpicker form-control" id="stateLst">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                
                <c:forEach items="${fileList}" var="option">
                  <option value="${option}">
                    <c:out value="${option}"></c:out>
                  </option>
                </c:forEach>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Upload</label>
            
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file" style="width: 468px;"><span>Choose file</span><input type="file" multiple/></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" data- backdrop="static">
                <spring:messagecode="ulearn.btn.upload.label"/>
              </button>
              
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">                       <spring:messagecode="ulearn.btn.cancel.label"/>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
      </div>
      
        </form>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: see if this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax

Comment: thanks, @Ron , but need the same in java

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at multipart/form-data posts.
Here is some additional info on the topic:

http://hmkcode.com/spring-mvc-upload-file-ajax-jquery-formdata/

[Upload file + Form Data + Spring MVC + JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498426/upload-file-form-data-spring-mvc-jquery)